# Cant pass data from JSONObject result to ListView

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm new to developing Android application using PHP and MySQL, I'm currently following a guide for a simple CRUD using Volley. I bumped into something which I can't populate my ListView with the JSONObject result. I already checked if my app got the api's result which it did still doesnt display anything on the ListView

JSONObject Result

[image]

Here's my code

```
 private void loadLogList(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, JSON_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    public void onResponse(String response){
                        try{
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray logsArray = obj.getJSONArray("logs");
                            System.out.print("Object :" +obj);

                            for(int i = 0;i < logsArray.length();i++){
                                JSONObject logObject = logsArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                LogsModel model = new LogsModel(logObject.getString("date"),
                                        logObject.getString("time_in"),
                                        logObject.getString("time_out"),
                                        logObject.getString("division"),
                                        logObject.getString("department"),
                                        logObject.getString("designation"),
                                        logObject.getString("log_content"));

                                        logList.add(model);
                            }
                            LogsAdapter adapter = new LogsAdapter(logList,getApplicationContext());
                            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                },
                new Response.ErrorListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Here is my ListView Adapter

```
public class LogsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LogsModel> {
private List<LogsModel> logList;

private Context context;

public LogsAdapter(List<LogsModel> logList, Context context){
    super(context,R.layout.layout,logList);
    this.logList = logList;
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout,null,true);

    TextView txtDate = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
    TextView txtTimeIn  = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txtTimeIn);
    TextView txtTimeOut  = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txtTimeOut);
    TextView txtDivision  = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txtDivision);
    TextView txtDesignation  = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txtDesignation);
    TextView txtDepartment  = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txtDepartment);
    TextView txtActivities = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.txtActivities);

    LogsModel logs = logList.get(position);

    txtDate.setText(logs.getDate());
    txtTimeIn.setText(logs.getTime_in());
    txtTimeOut.setText(logs.getTime_out());
    txtDivision.setText(logs.getDivision());
    txtDesignation.setText(logs.getDesignation());
    txtDepartment.setText(logs.getDepartment());
    txtActivities.setText(logs.getLog_content());

    System.out.println("Model" +logs);
    return listViewItem;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a class (in example it is YourRecordHolderClass) with constructor and getters to hold all your details. Then change your code to:

```
    //Create string to keep your details
//String logObTimeIn; etc.
                            //Before "try" create ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> location = null;
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                            location = new ArrayList<>();
                            JSONArray logsArray = obj.getJSONArray("logs");
                            HashMap<String, String> map;

                            for(int i = 0;i < logsArray.length();i++){
                                JSONObject logObject = logsArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                map = new HashMap<>();
                                    map.put("date", logObject.getString("date"));
                                    map.put("time_in", logObject.getString("time_in")),
                                    map.put("time_out", logObject.getString("time_out")),
                                    map.put("division", logObject.getString("division")),
                                    map.put("department", logObject.getString("department")),
                                    map.put("designation", logObject.getString("designation")),
                                    map.put("log_content", logObject.getString("log_content"));
                                    location.add(map);
                            }

                            if(location != null){
                                for(i = 0; i < location.size(); i++){
                                    logObDate = location.get(i).get("date").toString();
                                    logObTimeIn = location.get(i).get("time_in").toString();
                                    logObTimeOut = location.get(i).get("time_out").toString();
                                    logObDivision = location.get(i).get("division").toString();
                                    logObDepartment = location.get(i).get("department").toString();
                                    logObDesignation = location.get(i).get("designation").toString();
                                    logObContent = location.get(i).get("log_content").toString();

                            //instead of xyz create ArrayList in your main class and call it here
                            //private ArrayList<YourRecordHolderClass> records = new ArrayList<>();
                            xyx.add(new YourRecordHolderClass(logObDate, logObTimeIn, logObTimeOut, logObDivision, logObDepartment, logObDesignation, logObContent));
                            listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.myListView);
                            LogsAdapter adapter = new LogsAdapter(records, getApplicationContext());
                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }
```

Now change the constructor in your Adapter class:

```
public LogsAdapter(ArrayList<YourRecordHolderClass> records, Context context){
super(context,R.layout.layout,logList);
this.logList = records;
this.context = context;
```

Everything should be ok. Let me know how it works.

Comment: Still doesnt pass the result to textview

Comment: @TerenceDXsin Have you tried to change ArrayAdapter into BaseAdapter, it gives you more options?